# Why does a menu become transparent when hovering over an absolute/relative div?

Tags: css, jscrollpane, transparent

On my website, when I put a `jscrollpane` on the right side, my 2nd level leftmenu (displays when you hover to a menu) becomes transparent and sometimes loses focus: http://trantienhiensauxavanphuoc.com/vi/gia-pha-toan-toc

Another page doesn't have a `jscrollpane` and that works normally:
http://trantienhiensauxavanphuoc.com/

Can anybody can help me find the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following CSS in your code,

```
#sidebarmenu1 li ul{z-index:99999 !important;}
```

Comment: If you like this answer, upvote it by clicking the up-arrow above next to the answer. If you believe this answer addresses your question, accept it by clicking the the checkmark shape next to the question. This benefits you, the person that provided the answer, and helps others know that this question has been answered.